# How do I SELECT from 3 Tables with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display Rows based on a Search Query.
But, I have 3 Tables and want to search in all 3 if something is LIKE ('%$parameter%') the Parameter.

This is my current Code:

```
SELECT a.Name as aName
     , b.Name as bName
     , c.Name as cName 
  FROM TableA a
     , TableB b
     , TableC c 
 WHERE a.Name LIKE '%$parameter%' 
    OR b.Name LIKE '%$parameter%' 
    OR c.Name LIKE '%$parameter%'
```

And in PHP I do the following:

```
if($row['aName'] != ""){ echo $row['aName']; }
if($row['bName'] != ""){ echo $row['bName']; }
if($row['cName'] != ""){ echo $row['cName']; }
```

But this... just throws out every single row from all Tables, even them that dont even match the Parameter.

I couldn't find anything on google or stackoverflow that helps.

Please help!

Comment: what is the value of  `$parameter` ?

Comment: @Ali $parameter is what I enter in the Search Input, doesn't matter what I put in... Strings that are in one of the tables or some nonsense that isn't, it still shows 27.000 Results, with 3 Tables that only have about 5.000 Rows together

Comment: do `var_dump($parameter)` to check if it's not empty

Comment: reads like $paramater is blank it it returns 'everything'

Comment: When I use var dump this comes out: string(5) "Apple"

Comment: you need to join the three tables

Comment: `SELECT a.Name as aName, b.Name as bName, c.Name as cName FROM a JOIN a.Name = b.Name JOIN a.Name = c.Name WHERE a.Name LIKE '%$parameter%'`try this once

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Where does it define the Tables?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I tried the code and it doesnt show anything, even If I leave the $parameter empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should update your sql so it will not return 3 columns but 1 column and it will also simplify your php a little:

```
 SELECT a.Name as aName
  FROM TableA a
  WHERE a.Name LIKE '%$parameter%' 
 union
  SELECT b.Name as bName
  FROM TableB b
  WHERE b.Name LIKE '%$parameter%' 
 union
  SELECT c.Name as cName
  FROM TableC c
  WHERE c.Name LIKE '%$parameter%'
```

This way you will get only matched lines and you will save yourself from unnecessary full Cartesian product between 3 tables.

Answer (score 1):

Without any conditions for Joining your tables you just making a Cartesian Product (called as `Cross Join`), so you need to add conditions for joining tables to each other:

```
SELECT a.Name as aName
     , b.Name as bName
     , c.Name as cName 
  FROM TableA a
  INNER JOIN TableB b
         a.name = b.name /* they are should have the same data for matching OR if it's OK then you can use your "Primary Key Columns" for matching other tables*/
  INNER JOIN TableC c 
         ON a.name = c.name
  WHERE 
      a.Name LIKE '%$parameter%' 
      OR b.Name LIKE '%$parameter%' 
      OR c.Name LIKE '%$parameter%';
```